# How can I publish multiple asp.net-core applications at once

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 5 projects in 1 solution with 3 applications and 2 libraries. How do I publish each application?

[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2O3N.png)

Note: I don't know the ASP.NET. I just want to upload this project to server.

Comment: Your question is too broad, and frankly, saying something like, "Note: I don't know the ASP.NET. I just want to upload this project to server," is ridiculous. Do your research. Read the documentation. Try something. If you run into issues, *then* you can ask *specific* questions about those.

Comment: Actually I am python developer. I wrote that note because I hadn't much time. I have works to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a build script to publish EE.UI, EE.API and EE.Admin all together but for different addresses using [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21). You will need [publish profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) that you can create using Visual-Studio.

The other two projects are only libraries. When they are referenced, they will automatically be compiled with the executable projects.